# ER Diagram Transpose with relationships

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok so I know how to transpose ER diagram into relations but I am struggling on transposing the ER diagram with relationships.

Here is the example I have:
http://postimg.org/image/abd19wiyx/

Can anyone guide me through it? I don't need the final solution, I just need some hints on how to start. Thanks!